# Where is /usr/local/bin on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-line, bash

For context, i installed [apktools](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) software by moving file to C:\Windows and run the software from command prompt. I use windows 10 (also enabled windows subsystem for linux) and just installed ubuntu from microsoft store. However, even though i can execute the app from cmd, when i enter bash mode i get the error

```
Command apktool not found
```

From apktools installation guide for linux, the file must be moved to /usr/local/bin . But i don't know where is /usr/local/bin in windows, does anyone know where it is ?

Comment: What is this "bash mode"? Are you using git-bash? Is it WSL? Needs more details

Comment: @SathyajithBhat i installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my windows 10 and typed "bash" in cmd to enter bash mode